# State machine represented on DB, enforcement of state transition

Tags: postgresql, state-machine

I've got a finite state machine which represents the phases of a job.
I need to represent the states in a Postgres database. I would like to enforce the code correctness by forbidding updates from one state to the other unless the state machine allows so.

A naive way to accomplish my goal could be the acquisition of an *exclusive lock* on the table, within the transaction check the current state and the next state, abort with errors in case of invalid update.

This is clearly a performances killer, since I'm going to lock the *Job* table at each state transition.

Is there a way to accomplish the same goal via constraints?

Comment: what should happen, if incorrect transition attempted?

Comment: @Riliam, abort update, crash application

Comment: looks like use case for BEFORE UPDATE trigger. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: also, consider this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367332/sql-constraint-to-prevent-updating-a-column-based-on-its-prior-value

Comment: @Riliam, yes, seems an appropriate similar question

Comment: So, a trigger seems to be indeed appropriate. Is there a way to trigger a rollback? I think this would do:
```
create trigger test before update on "Job" for row when (OLD."status" = 'Init' and NEW."status" != 'Queued') execute procedure rollback()
```
But I would prefer not to declare a `rollback` function.

Comment: @Dacav: you don't need to rollback in the trigger, just [RAISE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) an exception and the outer transaction will be aborted with an error.

Comment: @MatheusOl yup! :) Found it https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/525D9505.1030209%40optionshouse.com#525D9505.1030209@optionshouse.com and I was able to implement it too. I was wondering if I really *need* to write a function for this, if I need I'll do. At this point the first who answer gets the cake :)

Comment: I would define function where all logic described, so `(OLD."status" = 'Init' and NEW."status" != 'Queued') ` will be not in trigger definition, but in function. For forbidden transitions, return null, this will prevent update (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trigger is the answer for your problem.

Let's consider simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE world (id serial PRIMARY KEY, state VARCHAR);
insert into world (state) values ('big bang');
insert into world (state) values ('stars formation');
insert into world (state) values ('human era');
```

Function that will be called by the trigger. Define your state machine logic here. RAISE EXCEPTION is useful, since you can provide custom message here.

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_world_change() RETURNS trigger as $check_world_change$
BEGIN
  IF OLD.state = 'big bang' AND NEW.state = 'human era' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Dont skip stars';
  END IF;
  IF OLD.state = 'stars formation' AND NEW.state = 'big bang' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Impossible to reverse order of things';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$check_world_change$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And define trigger for your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_world_change BEFORE UPDATE ON world 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_world_change();
```

Now, when you try to update state of one of the rows, you'll get error:

```
world=# select * from world;
 id |      state
----+-----------------
  2 | stars formation
  1 | human era
  3 | big bang
(3 rows)

world=# update world set state='human era' where state='big bang';
ERROR:  Wrong transition
world=# select * from world;
 id |      state
----+-----------------
  2 | stars formation
  1 | human era
  3 | big bang
(3 rows)
```

References:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-trigger.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html